# SailsJS verson ^1 need to set case sensitivity on queries to false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm using SailsJS with mongoDB. Recently I updated from sails o.12 to 1.2.3. All working fine until,

I found out that my queries are now case sensitive. I need to set it to false because of it caused much trouble in various scenarios and some are yet to be found. If any one has any idea please let me know immediately.

I tried adding `wlNext: { caseSensitive: false }` and it does not work anymore.

my versions,

```
    "sails": "^1.2.3",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-mongo": "^1.1.0",
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding this

`.meta({makeLikeModifierCaseInsensitive: true})`

in the `find` method.

i.e. the structure complete as follows

```
YourModel.find({
}).meta({makeLikeModifierCaseInsensitive: true}).then(function (result) {
 // Logic to result 
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and was searching for something to the whole db

Comment: Make sure you are on `sails-mongo@1.2.0` before you execute this new method. Update your `sails-mongo`.